# Let finite $G=AB;G_1,A_1,B_1$ Hall $π$-subgroups of $G,A,B$, resp.; $A_1,B_1\subseteq G_1$. Show $|G_1|=|A_1||B_1|/n,n$ max $π$-divisor of $|A\cap B|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to solve an exercise about Hall $\pi$-subgroups. The problem is the following:

We have a finite group $G=AB$ product of its subgroups $A$ and $B$. Then we have $G_1, A_1, B_1$ Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$, $A$, $B$, respectively. Moreover, $A_1$ and $B_1$ are both contained in $G_1$. If $n$ is the maximum $\pi$-divisor of $|A \cap B|$, how can I show that $|G_1|= \frac{|A_1| \cdot |B_1|}{n}$?

I know that $|G|= \frac {|A||B|}{|A \cap B|}$ and, since $A_1$ is contained in $G_1$, we have $|G_1|= |A_1||G_1 : A_1|$, but I can't exploit the information on $n$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward.

Write $|A|= a_\pi a_{\pi'}$, $|B| = b_\pi b_{\pi'}$ with $a_\pi,b_\pi$ $\pi$-numbers and $a_{\pi'}, b_{\pi'}$ $\pi'$-numbers. Then $|A_1| = a_\pi$ and $|B_1| = b_\pi$.  We know that $|A \cap B| = n n'$ with $n$ a $\pi$-number and $n'$ a $\pi'$-number.

So $$|G| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|} = \frac{a_\pi a_{\pi'}b_\pi b_{\pi'}}{nn'} = \left(\frac{|A_1||B_1|}{n}\right)\left(\frac{a_{\pi'}b_{\pi'}}{n'}\right),$$
and the $\pi$-part of $|G|$, is equal to $|G_1| = \frac{|A_1||B_1|}{n}$.

Comment: Very clear, thank you.